# How to support dual screen on android with an interactive screen?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, multiple-monitors

I am making a game running on an android phone with an interactive station, the station looks like an interactive screen,  when the phone connected to the station ,the station would show the same desktop content as phone and can launch app and do anything as same as phone ,it can also launch different app on phone and station respectively. I wanna achieve that launch my app and can see a different view in phone screen and station screen, both phone screen, and station screen can receive user input event.

I have tried to use,

*ExtCamera.SetTargetBuffers(Display.displays[1].colorBuffer, Display.displays[1].depthBuffer);*

to output what ExtCamera view to the secondary screen.

I can see different camera view in the station screen and phone screen, but the station screen can not receive user input, I wonder it because this method is only to render a texture to screen so it can not receive user input ? or there is another way to achieve this goal? I knew that android native offer class presentation to support multi-display, but it seems a large workload between android and unity to interact.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is a interactive station exactly? You can have two cameras showing different parts of the same scene.

Comment: Its a touchscreen.I already have two cameras showing different parts , one camera to phone and another to station.But only phone can receive user input.

Comment: Unity can only take input from supported platforms. Some mobile OS are supported such as iOS, Andoird. But I dont think your Station is supported by unity. And also your app is installed on mobile not station so it can only take inputs from your mobile.